# jQuery alert after form submit and redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to invoke an alert box after a form is fully submitted AND the page is redirected, but don't exactly know how to go about it.

After a user registers with the site, it redirects them to their profile page.

What I want to do is, IF the request came from the from with ID of new_user, AND after the user gets redirected to their profile page, invoke an alert.

So on the profile page, after coming from the new_user form, invoke an alert.

Right now I am doing this:

```
$('form#new_user').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // don't submit multiple times
    this.submit(); // use the native submit method of the form element
    alert("Testing page load.");
});
```

But that invokes the pop up after the form is submitted, before the user gets to the profile page.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use AJAX to get a response then decide what to do.

Comment: Correct, I want to see the alert on the profile page, but only after a registration - not all the time.

Comment: Can you just pass in a parameter to the profile page after a registration?

Comment: check for form submission on profile page and alert like
`if(form is submitted){ print "<script>alert("Testing page load.");</script>";}`

Answer (score 0):

hi i think you can do this easily using AJAX
pass the variables to the ajax page and on SUCCESS show the alert box which you want to show.
i think it is better to use AJAX to Jquery for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea on how you could do it:

```
#inside your RegistrationsController

def create
  user = User.new(user_params)
  if user.save
    redirect_to user_profile_path(user, from: 'registration), notice: "Successful registration."
  else
    # code for handling error in registration
  end
end
```

Now that you have a param `:from` passed to the user_profile_path every time a user is just registered, you can do something like this in your JS for your profile page

```
if(window.location.search == 'from=registration') {
  alert("Redirected from registration!");
}
```

Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Where you need this alert message? in your registration page or profile page?

If you want to invoke alert in your registration page, better you should us ajax post method for submitting the form.

If you want to display alert message in your profile page, pass a value as query string and write jquery alert function based on that query string value.